# CSS counters resetting without any counter-reset property specified

Tags: html, css

[I made a quick mock-up of the problem at hand](http://randomguy32.bplaced.de/counters/). ([more compact version to avoid possible confusion](http://randomguy32.bplaced.de/counters/short/)) Its basic layout is identical to the document I'm working with; it's only missing most of the styling.

Basically I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- Every `<p>` element shall be proceded by a number, automatically increasing by 1 with each new paragraph.
- At every `<h4>` element (the big, green numbers), this counter (named *vers*) is supposed to reset back to 1.
- A `<p>` element placed immediately after an `<h4>` doesn't show its counter number. Now looking at my page you see the problem already:
- Instead of incrementing constantly until an `<h4>` is reached, the counter resets at every `<h3>` element (blue), despite there being no counter-reset specified.
- I just cannot figure out how to prevent the *vers* counter from jumping back to 1 at the wrong places.

Now here's the catch: It used to worked correctly.

Previously I had an empty `<var>` element at the beginning of every paragraph and used this to show the counter value because it was easier to style.

However this turned out to be quite tedious, so I switched over the counter to the paragraphs directly. And this was when it started to do this weird thing instead of counting properly.

Literally all I did was changing `var::before` to `p::before` in the stylesheet and removing all `<var>` elements from the document. The counter properties defined didn't change one bit.

I hope there is a way to make this thing work without reverting back to using `<var>` again.

Comment: Your last CSS ruleset (`article h4 + p::before`) is unterminated. That may not necessarily be the problem, since browsers will terminate it for you, but I just thought I'd point it out. Also, see if you can include a shortened version of your HTML and CSS within the question.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the `div.chapter` elements? The counters are getting reset because the h4 elements are children of those divs, and the browser has to step out of the current div in order to find the next h4. The var elements should not make a difference, assuming you had put them in the same place as the p::before pseudo-elements now reside.

Comment: I'm baffled. I moved the <h4>s out of the div.chapters and now it's counting correctly. But why did it work with the var elements? I'm also pretty sure I tried it previously with h4 both in and outside the chapters to see if it made any difference and it worked in neither case.

Comment: That's trial-and-error for you :)

Comment: I'm just baffled if my edits made that easier to read :3

Comment: Now there's a new problem: `article h4 + p::before` obviously doesn't work anymore because the h4 and p are no longer directly adjacent. Seems like I need to mark every p that shouldn't show the counter manually now.